# Need Help: Copying Row Into Many Rows Created below (Excel VBA)

Tags: excel, insert, range, named-ranges

New user here who is also very new to Excel VB.

At the moment, I have a macro which [does what you see here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnrq4.png)

Essentially, I have 2 columns which can sometimes have cells which contain vertically stacked lines of data in each cell. Each of those lines is split out and put into newly inserted rows below (one line of data in the cell per row).

The problem I am having now, is that while the new rows now contain data in the two columns which had to be split (34 and 35), the remaining cells are empty. I am having trouble bringing the remaining 38 columns down into the newly-created rows. You can see what I mean in the image I posted. Two new rows were created and I need to fill them with the content of row 1 (fill in to the shaded area).

Here is my code right now. The part that is commented out is me trying to fill the empty space. The un-commented code does what you see in the image.

```
Sub main()
Dim iRow As Long, nRows As Long, nData As Long
Dim IDVariables As Range
Dim arr As Variant


With Worksheets("UI").Columns("AH") 
    nRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 
    For iRow = nRows To 2 Step -1 
        With .Cells(iRow) 
            arr = Split(.Value, vbLf) 
            nData = UBound(arr) + 1 
            If nData > 1 Then 
                    .EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(nData - 1).Insert 
                    .Resize(nData).Value = Application.Transpose(arr) 
                    .Offset(, 1).Resize(nData).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(.Offset(, 1).Value, vbLf)) 
                    'Set IDVariables = Range("A" & iRow & ":AG" & iRow)
                    'IDVariables.Select
                    'Selection.Copy
                    'Range("A" & (iRow + 1) & ":A" & (iRow + nData -1)).Select
                    'Selection.Paste             
            End If
        End With
    Next iRow
End With
```

End Sub

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share some sample data before and after the macro has run? Do not need a full page, just enough rows to get the point across visually

Comment: Sure urdearboy, I updated the post per your suggestions so it is easier to read and understand.

Comment: Hey I'm really sorry for the delayed response. I was really busy was school and had to take yesterday off. I ran the program, and it only seems to insert one row below the row which has a vertically stacked cell, rather than inserting the number of rows -1 which corresponds with the number of stacked items in the cell. It does successfully copy-paste the all the other cells however, so that part is working. Once again sorry for the delayed response, and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm late doing this but I figured it out. I'll post my solution for anyone who has a similar problem.

```
Sub main()
Dim iRow As Long, nRows As Long, nData As Long
Dim arr As Variant
Dim IDVariables, Comments, AllocationCheck As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Worksheets("PRM2_Computer").Columns("AH")
    nRows = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row        
    For iRow = nRows To 2 Step -1
        With .Cells(iRow)
            arr = Split(.Value, vbLf)
            nData = UBound(arr) + 1
            If nData = 1 Then
                Range("AI" & iRow) = 1
                Range("AK" & iRow) = "Single Industry"
            End If
            If nData > 1 Then
                    .EntireRow.Offset(1).Resize(nData - 1).Insert
                    .Resize(nData).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
                    .Offset(, 1).Resize(nData).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(.Offset(, 1).Value, vbLf))
                    .Offset(, 2).Resize(nData).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(.Offset(, 2).Value, vbLf))
                    Set Comments = Range("AL" & iRow & ":AM" & iRow)
                    Comments.Copy Range("AL" & (iRow + 1) & ":AL" & (iRow + nData - 1))
                    Set AllocationCheck = Range("AK" & (iRow) & ":AK" & (iRow + nData - 1))
                    AllocationCheck.Value = Application.Sum(Range("AI" & iRow & ":AI" & (iRow + nData - 1)))
                    Set IDVariables = Range("A" & iRow & ":AG" & iRow)
                    IDVariables.Copy Range("A" & (iRow + 1) & ":A" & (iRow + nData - 1))
            End If
        End With
    Next iRow
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

*Tested and working fine....*

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReCode()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, arr
LR = ws.Range("AH" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = LR To 2 Step -1
    If InStr(ws.Range("AH" & i), vbLf) Then
        ws.Range("A" & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert xlUp
            ws.Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Copy ws.Range("A" & i + 1)
            arr = Split(ws.Range("AH" & i), vbLf)
            ws.Range("AH" & i) = arr(0)
            ws.Range("AH" & i + 1) = arr(1)
        arr = ""
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am only  a part-time employee (Mon and Tues) and am not allowed to bring the data set home. I do not have time right now, but I will  try and run this on a small data set to see how it goes